# Rails implicit render in templates from multiple controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have code like `render @posts` to render my posts collection in an index template which the `PostsController` renders.

Now I have an `Admin::PostsController` that also should render the collection but when my posts controller renders `@posts` it looks for the `admin/posts/_post.html.erb` partial. Do I now have to write the partial path explicity? Is this feature by design or a bug? It doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @Malestor oh shoot How did I missed that , but taking a point from your question rails render the partial(if not explicitly define) from view directory of that controller so If I have to give an answer for that then I would suggest it as a valid `feature` instead of bug since it give me flexibility of knowing the fact that the partial for the object define in my controller lies inside the view directory of that controller itself (until explicitly defined though) Correct If I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to supply the path explicitly. And yes, this is by design.

It actually makes sense because Rails is a MVC framework and if you create a controller under a different namespace one would expect separate views for that controller too. Think about convenience, if you wanted to quickly bootstrap an application with a few simple commands, an application where there's a public view of posts and an admin view where all of the admin goodies for editing are, you would EXPECT to have a different directory to store all that admin views.

Answer (score 0):

`render @posts` is a shortcut for a longer method signature.

In case of `PostsController`, it is a short cut for `render :partial => "post", :collection => @posts`; the partial is `_post.html.erb` and it is expected to be in `app/views/posts` folder.

In case of `Admin::PostsController`, it is a short cut for `render :partial => "admin#post/post", :collection => @posts`; the partial is `_post.html.erb`, and it is expected to be in `app/views/admin/posts` folder.

If you want a different partial to be used, you should specify it explicitly.

See the [`Rendering Collections`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) section of Rails Guides page on Layouts & Rendering for detailed explanation.